# Show current date

Tags: javascript

I am using the following to get the current date:-

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
var newdate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
```

If I `alert(newdate);` it shows:-

> 3/06/2013

Is there any way I can display this as:-

> 03/06/2013

Comment: Dates are handled differently by each browser so I use a library called dateJS.  If you have the ability to use that it will make your life easier.  It has functions that allow you to call new Date().toString("MM/dd/yyyy") and it works across all browsers that I have tested (IE 7+, FF, Chrome, and Safari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid using a library, and don't mind an extra line in your JavaScript:

```
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate(),
    dd = parseInt(day, 10) < 10 ? '0' + day : day;
```

Answer (score 3):

With plain Javascript, only manually

```
if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;
if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [JQuery DateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat):

```
$.format.date(dateObj.toString(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

var mydate=new Date();
alert(mydate.toString('dd/MM/yyyy'));

Answer (score 0):

```
function padWithZeroes(number, width)
{
    while (number.length < width)
        number = '0' + number;
    return number;
}
```

Now call `day = padWithZeroes(day, 2)` (and likewise for the month) before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it and create your own format:

```
var splitTime = newDate.split("/");
var day = splitTime[0];
var month = splitTime[1];
var year = splitTime[2];

if (day < 10){
    day = "0" + day;
}

var myDate = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
```

Living demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/rtqpp/

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following:

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = ('0' + (dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1) ).slice( -2 );;
var day = ('0' + (dateObj.getUTCDate() + 1) ).slice( -2 );
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
var newdate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
```